# Sticky footer issue with Keypad and small content pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had an issue where the footer would not stick to the bottom when the keypad opened. Someone suggested a fix which worked however, I just discovered that this caused a new issues on other pages. Please see thread here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2...ens-boostrap-3

I need to have the footer stick when the keypad opens and when it closes and also when there is little text on a page. Can someone guide me as to how I can achieve this ? I am pretty new to boostrap and I am totally at a loss now.

from what I can see I think it seems to only be effecting 320 X 480 and I am guess smaller. I do not have that size to test in FF. ( again new at mobile dev here )

demo here
https://corker-chisel.codio.io/Form.html

nav is set to the two different pages to the issues I face.

Thanks you so much for any and all help

screen shots of suggested fix -- demo  -- corker-chisel.codio.io/No_StickyFooterForm.html corker-chisel.codio.io/No_StickyFooterPage2.html
[image] [image]

Gina

Comment: I hate fixed footers. Try with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/HYf7q/5/

Footer have `position: absolute`, but body have `position: relative`. In that way, footer is always on the bottom. Look at this demo, and ask me if you don't get it

Comment: Nope that didn't work. See https://corker-chisel.codio.io/Page2.html I added your changes and the footer jumps up like it was before ?

Comment: I create a sample with your changes

https://corker-chisel.codio.io/No_StickyFooterForm.html
https://corker-chisel.codio.io/No_StickyFooterPage2.html

Comment: Nice Job on No_stickyFooterForm. I,like a user have a better experience with your page, because I'm not seeing footer all the time. Little note: you dont need to put width on wrapper, footer is allways on bottom because of `position: absolute` and body have `position: relative`, so basicly, if you don't have content on page, footer will be visible at the bottom, and if you have content, footer will be pushed down because it has absolute position relative to your body, not the viewport. And most important, footer is not visible on phone when input is focused.

Comment: I am a little confused. I don't see any width on the wrapper class ? or were you just telling me for informational purposes  :)

as for my page https://corker-chisel.codio.io/No_StickyFooterPage2.html I still see the footer in the middle of the page and not at the bottom ? so your suggestion does not seem to be working unless I have something off ?

and the https://corker-chisel.codio.io/No_StickyFooterForm.html the footer is overriding the buttons with this solution ?

please see screen shots

Comment: Its overriding because you are using responsive design, and your footer height is bigger on small devices. You need to change footerfix to be, let say, `6rem`. If you have responsive design, you must thing in that way. Make changes in responsive way. I will look at page2 now to see what you did there.

Comment: hmm, something is overriding you setup. If you change your browser height, footer is acting normal, its at the bottom, as it should be, but, if you change browsers width, to act like small device, than footer is messy. Conclusion: Something in your responsive design is changing footer setup. You must check what it is. I know, it's a pain, but it will pay off.

Comment: Sorry for spamming here, but, try to include main file last, or make another css file, and include it at the bottom,after override.css. And be sure to include `!important` at some values. In that way, footer will not be changed by other css files. And ofcourse, if you have diferences in height with footer, make media queeryes for this couple classes.